# Why does VMAF show lower then 100 on same image?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm testing ways to compare image similarity using ffmpeg. I'm looking at using SSIM, PSNR and VMAF.
For reference, I'm running the comparison with duplicated sources and expect a score of 100%.
Running SSIM like this:
`ffmpeg -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=red:duration=10:size=1280x720:rate=30 -f lavfi -i color=red:duration=10:size=1280x720:rate=30 -filter_complex "ssim" -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 1 -f null`
Gives a perfect score:
 `[Parsed_ssim_0 @ 0x6000015844d0] SSIM Y:1.000000 (inf) U:1.000000 (inf) V:1.000000 (inf) All:1.000000 (inf)`

Running PSNR like this:
`ffmpeg -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=red:duration=10:size=1280x720:rate=30 -f lavfi -i color=red:duration=10:size=1280x720:rate=30 -filter_complex "PSNR" -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 1 -f null`
Gives a perfect score:
 `[Parsed_psnr_0 @ 0x600001478630] PSNR y:inf u:inf v:inf average:inf min:inf max:inf`

Running **VMAF** like this:
`ffmpeg -hide_banner -f lavfi -i color=red:duration=10:size=1280x720:rate=30 -f lavfi -i color=red:duration=10:size=1280x720:rate=30 -filter_complex "libvmaf" -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 1 -f null`
I get:
 `[Parsed_libvmaf_0 @ 0x600002c10630] VMAF score: 97.428043`

Why does VMAF give less the perfect score for the duplicated inputs?
Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: the VMAF engine isn't comparing pixel to pixel. The engine calculates some objective metrics for each stream (subject and reference); the final VMAF score then is *a prediction of a machine learning model*, hence the imperfect score.

Long answer: read the discussion at https://github.com/Netflix/vmaf/issues/76